# How to create directory/ folder dynamically to store uploaded images, using AnagularJs, Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directory, mkdir

anyone have a idea to about creating dynamic folder/directory to store uploaded images using angluarjs/javascript?

is it possible.? I tried lot with multer and bus boy, but its store file in parent folder, I just want move file  directly to child folder dynamically, whenever the new upload has done?

Comment: type in Google "how to create dynamic directory using XXX", where XXX is Java, PHP, JQuery, WHATEVER_BACK_END_TECHNOLOGY_YOU_ARE_USING

Comment: @DmitriAlgazin dude.. i'd tried lot since 2 wks but i cant get any ideas to achieve this.. :(

Comment: what back-end you are using? I mean is your Angular running on Tomcat, Jetty, or any other server?

Answer (score 1):

If it ain't late to answer, You can use HTML5's filesystem api to create directories and store what you will be downloading by simply

```
window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, function(fs) {
  fs.root.getDirectory('YourDirectoryName', {create: true}, function(entry) {
    ...
  }, err);
}, err);
```